# How can I retrieve the most recent simplelogin users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a firebase call that accepts a number and returns all simplelogins greater than or equal to that number?

For the avoidance of doubt, I'm not referring to data in my app, I'm referring to the list of users maintained separately by Firebase under the Login & Auth tab.

When I refresh users, the ajax call made by the firebase graphical debugger is this:
https://auth.firebase.com/v2/MYAPP/users?forge=true&token=XXX

But I can't get this to work with my secure JSON web token ("firebase secrets")

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think I may have been unclear in my initial question. I've expanded the detail. But I'm pretty sure your link refers to data inside one of my app instances, but the simplelogin data is maintained separately by firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase keeps the email/password information for users of your application in a separate database.

There is currently no official public API to access your email/password users. You can however see the users in the Login & Auth part of your Firebase's Dashboard.

Most applications that use Firebase Authentication store a copy of their users inside their database, i.e. under a `/users` node. They can then access it through Firebase's regular APIs.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  I recall finding a url that included the app's secret token and returned all users. Unfortunately, search as I might I can't seem to find it again. In any case, I'd rather not request ALL users each time. Think I should rearrange my db to store user data as you say.  Thanks again.